# How to append an HTML string, from template_process_page() to $page_bottom region in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal 7.

I'm trying to append an HTML string, from inside the `template_process_page()` function in my module.

Is there any tricky way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In short, add it to the $variables array inside your preprocess function, such [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6). See the handbook page on [Setting up variables for use in a template](http://drupal.org/node/223430), for more information.